# Assistance needed with downloading PDF in R

Tags: r, pdf, web-scraping, web-crawler, data-science

In the code below, the `handle` portion seems to be giving me an error every time I try to download the PDFs.

```
url <- "http://brocktonpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/"
filename <- paste0(format(AllDays, '%Y/%m/%m%d%Y'), '.pdf')
filenames_list <- str_extract_all(filenames, 'uploads.+pdf')

downloadPDF <- function(filename, baseurl, folder, handle){
      dir.create(folder, showWarnings = FALSE)
      fileurl <- str_c(baseurl, filename)
      if (!file.exists(str_c(folder,"/",filename))) {    
            content <- getBinaryURL(fileurl, curl = handle )
            writeBin(content, str_c(folder,"/",filename))
            Sys.sleep(1)
      }
}

handle <- getCurlHandle(useragent = str_c(R.version$platform,
                  R.version.string, sep = ", "), 
                  httpheader = c(from = "jomisilfe@gmail.com"))

l_ply(filenames_list, downloadPDF,
      baseurl = "http://brocktonpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/",
      folder = "Police_logs")
```

I have run out of ideas on how to download those PDFs.
Here is how I generated the links to all the PDFs.

```
prefix <- "http://brocktonpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/"
AllDays <- seq.Date(from = as.Date('2015-01-01'), to = Sys.Date(), by = "day")
links <- paste0(prefix, format(AllDays, '%Y/%m/%m%d%Y'), '.pdf')
print(links)
```

ps: If you can think of other ways to download the PDFs, please share your code.
 NOTE that some URLs might give an error, since sometimes days and months are without leading zero when they are less than 10.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do it this way:
By examining the urls, sometimes there is no leading zero before days and months less than ten.

Here I'm creating all the urls with leading zeros where days and months are less than ten.

```
prefix <- "http://brocktonpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/"
AllDays <- seq.Date(from = as.Date('2015-01-01'), to = Sys.Date(), by = "day")
links1 <- paste0(prefix, format(AllDays, '%Y/%m/%m%d%y'), '.pdf')
```

Here I'm creating all the urls with without leading zeros where days and months are less than ten.

```
AllDays_NL <- gsub("0", "", format(AllDays, '%m%d%y'))
links2 <- paste0(prefix, format(AllDays, '%Y/%m/'), AllDays_NL,'.pdf')
```

Since there is not a clear pattern on when we do and don't have a leading zero, we will put the two lists together and extract the data whenever we have a match

```
link <- c(links1,links2)

filename <- paste0(format(AllDays, '%Y_%m_%d'),'.pdf')
dest <- tempfile(fileext = ".pdf")

for (x in 1:length(link)) {

      if (!file.exists(filename[x])) {
            download.file(link[x],dest, mode = 'wb')
      }

}
```